# Offline Maps showing blank screen on Simulator as well as on App

Tags: codenameone

I have an app i want to use offline maps and have followed all the steps outlined here https://github.com/shannah/CN1OfflineMaps but i its showing a blank screen.

Comment: Do you see anything in the console? Do you have a downloaded map in place?

Comment: Yes i downloaded one from http://openmaptiles.com and compiled it into cn1tiles.  TileMile app was saying it needs 30K hours + it had an error (code ESSL) to create mbtile files.

Comment: So did you do that and resolve the issue?

Comment: Still struggling...any other ways to solve this challenge

Comment: I'll need a bit more details about what's working and what isn't to help here

Comment: Which dataset did you download?  Please provide a link.  Also please be more precise in reporting the steps that you took, and the error messages that you received, so that I can follow your steps and their output exactly.

Comment: The error i am now getting is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: create image failed for the given image data of length: 1996

The MBTile file i downloaded https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/tileset/osm/africa/zimbabwe/harare/